# Batch processing mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, batching

I am trying to figure out a way to process documents such that I can add documents until a certain count (say 100). Once that 100th document is inserted, Mongodb should fire an event so that I can read all 100 records and batch process them in JS.

I am new to mongodb and I am still doing a lot of research. Any ideas how I could achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Change stream seems to be your friend  .. , also you can check bulk insert ...

Comment: What processing are you looking to do with these documents?

Comment: For a set of 100 docs, I want to get the hash of each document, add it to a map and put the map of hashes on a blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [intro](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams)  or [change events structure](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/) or [main docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/)